# What exactly does an ArrayList store?

Tags: c#, collections

I know I can add object of any type to an `ArrayList` instance. If I get it right, then reference types are casted to objects (value types are boxed). Also, does an `ArrayList` actually store lists of objects of reference type object?

Answer (score 4):

Internally the [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) class uses a fixed size array `object[]` (object array) for storage. When you add elements those elements are automatically copied to their respective indexes in the array. When the max size is reached a new array is created with a larger size and the elements are recopied. So it's just a convenience wrapper around a static object array.

Comment: -1 No, it's not a static array, it's a regular array. Also, an array can never be resized, when the array is full a new array is created and the items are copied.

Comment: @Guffa, maybe I didn't use the right term, but what is the difference between a static array and a regular array? That's why I preferred to provide an example in my answer with `object[]` to clear any ambiguity. As far as the resizing is concerned I thought that it was obvious that when saying resize for a static array this means the creation of a new array. It was just so obvious to me but I agree that I must have stated it more clearly. I will update.

Comment: @Darin: I think Guffa's objecting to the word "static" specifically because he assumed you meant `static` in the C# sense. @Guffa: I'm pretty sure Darin meant "static" as in *statically typed* (e.g., it doesn't use an `int[]` for integers, a `string[]` for strings, etc.)—right, Darin?

Comment: @Dan Tao, when I used the term *static array* (maybe a wrong term) I meant a fixed size array => `System.Array`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: A static variable is a member of the class instead of a member of the instance. That would mean that separate instances of `ArrayList` could not have separate data.

Comment: @Guffa, OK, sorry for me using a wrong term. I didn't really meant anything like static access modifier when I was talking about a static array. I mean a fixed size array. You are correct that this could lead to a confusion. I have updated once again my answer :-)

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: All arrays in .NET have a fixed size, there is no other kind.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` does not store objects, but merely the references to those objects.

Comment: @FreeAslnBeer Thanks; was looking for this answer. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` is essentially a wrapper around an `object[]`, with functionality to track space in the array and grow it (double it) as necessary. Note that usually `List<T>` is preferred, but to answer the question: yes, it just stores the references to the `object`s, which may well be boxed value-types.

A `List<T>` is pretty much the same, but around a `T[]`, which means value types can be stored without boxing. Reference-types are still stored as references. You also get more type safety; i.e. you can't add the wrong thing nor cast a retrieved item improperly.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList` is similar to `List<object>` and was created before .NET had generics.

It can store anything that derives from `object`, which is all reference and value types. So you could use it to store a lists of objects.

Answer (score 1):

The internal storage for an `ArrayList` is an object array (`object[]`).

When storing reference types in the `ArrayList`, the reference is just cast to `object` and stored in the array. The reference type instance itself contains information about it's type, so it's possible to cast it back to the actual type when you get it from the `ArrayList`.

Value types are boxed inside an object, and the reference to that object is stored in the array. The object contains information about what type the value is, so that it can be unboxed correctly when you get it from the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

They store any `object`.

Meaning it's possible to fill them with strings, integers, classes as long as they have been instantiated as an object.